# Acquiring the reference to an element of an STL container in a C++11 range-based 'for' loop

Tags: c++, stl, reference, for-loop, iterator

```
for (Something something : setOfSomething)          // OK
for (Something const& something : setOfSomething)   // OK
for (Something& something : setOfSomething)         // ERROR

error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Something&'
from expression of type 'const Something'
```

Since when does iterator return `const Something`? It should return either `Something&` or `Something const&`. And since range-based 'for' loop is interpreted like [that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), I have no plausible explanation for what's going on.

**Edit:** I'm talking about `unordered_set` rather than `set`, sorry about this confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't mutate the members of a `set` because that could violate the `set` invariants. So the compiler restricts you to getting const references or copies back out.

Comment: What kind of invariants can be broken if I modify MY object. The memory location and size which it occupies stays untouched - and these two things are the only ones which `set` is supposed to control. In addition, what if I have my own container? Why would compiler impose this kind of restriction on my containers? To be honest, it looks like a dirty hack.

Comment: The ordering of the objects in the `set` could be changed if you update parts of your object compared by the comparison of the `set`. If this problem is happening with a container other than `std::set` or any of its relatives (multi, unordered, etc) then could you please edit the specifics and more code into your question?

Comment: It's my problem then - I am an idiot then, but its not the compiler's business. Moreover, I can yet modify it inside an old-style iterator loop.

Comment: @Haroogan: You can't modify `set` elements in an iterator loop, or any other way, unless you deliberately invoke undefined behaviour using `const_cast`. `set` elements (and ordered associative keys in general) are always immutable, in order to preserve the ordering.

Comment: `unordered_set<Something>::iterator` returns `Something&` on dereference, doesn't it?

Comment: @Haroogan: Not anymore. It did in C++03, I think, but the Committee accurately fixed it. If you know in advance that some member does not break the `set`'s invariants, then declare it `mutable` and offer a `const` accessor.